# A sample application on calling the webservices from android, which is returning the error, "Unfortunately,MyTest has stopped"

Tags: android

I have a code, which makes a call to the web service provided by www,tempuri.org. 
While I am trying to run the application, the application is stopping unexpectedly and showing the message - "Unfortunately, MyTest has stopped".. Here is my java file -

MainActivity.java :-

```
package com.example.mytest;


import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelciusToFarenheit";
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelciusToFarenheit";
    public static final String NAMESPACE= "http://tempuri.org/";
    public static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
    TextView tv;
    SoapEnvelope se;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        SoapObject Request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("Celcius","32");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sse = new SoapSerializationEnvelope (se.VER11);
        sse.dotNet=true;
        sse.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        HttpTransportSE abt = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try
        {
            abt.call(SOAP_ACTION,se);
              SoapObject resultString=(SoapObject)sse.getResponse();   
              String resultData=resultString.getProperty(0).toString();

            tv.setText("Status :"+resultString);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The logcat is as follows -

```
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.example.mytest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-10 01:35:10.421: E/AndroidRuntime(1077):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am new to develop web services with android. Can you please suggest me, what to do with this?

Comment: since you are starting i would suggest you to read about Volley library, it's better to start with what's new and better, here is a video you could watch, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

**XML:**

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/web_service"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
    android:text="Web Service" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fetch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**ACTIVITY:**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button web_service;
TextView fetch_service;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fetch_service = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetch);
    web_service = (Button) findViewById(R.id.web_service);
    web_service.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myasynctask MAT = new myasynctask();
            MAT.execute();
        }
    });
}

class myasynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String str;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();
            str = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.d("WebRespone", str);
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fetch_service.setText(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

}
    }
```

**Manifest:**
add the following thins in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you are not using threads or asyntask post honeycomb you will get `NetWorkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks a lot dude wait i will change it. yes i knew it will give strictmode error.

Comment: I am using Asyntask, updated the INTERNET permission in the manifest file also, even then also the application is terminating unexpectedly.

Comment: Can you post your error log?because this code is working for me

Comment: @keerthi use SoapPrimitive instead of SoapObject while getting response

Comment: @Keerthi have you got output?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do network related operation on the main ui thread. You should use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`.

You are doing Network Related operation on the ui thread. You will get `NetworkOnMainThredException` in api level 11 and above.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

AsyncTask docs :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I suspect you do not have the jar file under libs folder
Make sure you have added the ksoap jar file to your libs folder.

Download at http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&

You can also use thread but you cannot updte ui from the backgound thread. You should update ui on the ui thread. So asynctask makes it easier.

Example : FahrenHeitToCelsius. Similarly you can call appropriate soap methods for CelciusToFarenheit. Same steps to be followed

```
 public class FirstScreen extends Activity
 {
 private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
 private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
 private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
SoapObject result;
 Button b;
 EditText et;
 int value;
 TextView tv;
 ProgressDialog pd;

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pd= new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("Making Soap Request");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    et= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            value=Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            new one1().execute();
        }

    });


}

 private class one1 extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, SoapObject> {

  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
      pd.show();
  }
protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);    

    //Use this to add parameters
    request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",value);         

    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);          

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;         

    try {
          HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);                
          androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
          result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

    } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();

    }           
    return result;
}

 protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result)
 {
  pd.dismiss();
if(result != null)
{
      tv.setText("Result = "+result.getProperty(0).toString());
}
else
{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="FahrenheitToCelsius" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="MakeRequest" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Result" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Lastly make sure you have internet permission in manifest file

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Snap Shot.

[image]

Comment: I have pasted the code as it is, cleared the errors and tried to run it. the activity has loaded and when I typed some value and clicked the "Make Request" button, the progress dialog appeared and unfortunately, the application has closed. Why this might have happened? I did not make any changes in the code.

Comment: @Keerthi it means a crash. crash means some usefull info is logged in logcat post the same updating your question along with new code

Comment: @Keerthi seems the latest soap jar is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/LvgwviVg3h8. ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar. make sure you the latest. not sure if this is the latest.

Comment: there is no change in the behaviour of the application, even after updating to the latest soap jar. As it is, it is terminating.

Comment: @Keerthi i don't get it. i tried it and it works for me. if you can pls post the stacktrace. its a crash you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Nirmal's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159035/2162226) did the trick for me.  However, I had to update action and namespace as follows:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
```

I figured out what the correct values should be by:

1. Going to the web service page: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx
2. Clicking the service description link: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL
3. Searching for the strings (case-insensitive) "action" and "namespace" in that xml, and then use the values they have

Answer (score 0):

I have received the same exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject at    
 com.example.soap_ksoap2_lino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
```

I think that the .jar file from code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android is only for compilation. It has no classes. All other .jars also don't work.
I have abandoned the KSOAP2 API strategy, and I try now to use the HttpPost whose .jar is already present in the Eclipse ADT.

Here is my code: [Sending SOAP request from Android. Server responses: "Server was unable to process request. "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229611/sending-soap-request-from-android-server-responses-server-was-unable-to-proce)

I receive a response from the w3schools server, however the server responds: "Server was unable to process request".