# Sending SOAP request from Android. Server responses: "Server was unable to process request. "

Tags: android, soap, request

I try to sent a SOAP query request for Android to the w3schools server, where it converts the temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit degrees, but I receive the following response from the server:

```
Server was unable to process request. 
---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. 
Line 1, position 1.
```

The servier is on: 
http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx. 
And the SOAP request message structure we can find on: http://w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit.
Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String URL =           
           "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpResponse response;
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("" +
      "POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx HTTP/1.1" +
      "Host: w3schools.com" +
      //"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" +
      //"Content-Length: length" +
      "SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit\"" +
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                     "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +
             "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
     "<soap:Body>" +
       "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
           "<Celsius>24</Celsius>" +
       "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>" +
     "</soap:Body>" +
       "</soap:Envelope>");

   HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
   request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

   tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   try {
     List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myxml", sb.toString()));
     request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

     response = httpclient.execute(request);
     String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     //Here we should parse the response xml
     //But for quicker way, we will display the whole response.
     tv.setText("Temperature in Fahrenheit is: " + response_string);
     Log.v("responseString", response_string)

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
    }
 }
```

I would appreciate if you guys could help me out.
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159008/an-sample-application-on-calling-the-webservices-from-android-which-is-returnig/18159070#18159070. check this if it helps.

Comment: @Raghunandan. Thank you Raghunandan, I first tried with KSOAP2, but the .jars code.google.com are providing are not good. They either are good just for compilation with no definition class, or are not good at all. I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject at com.example.soap_ksoap2_lino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
Maybe, could you please send me a good working ksoap2-android...jar?

Comment: make sure you add the jar to the libs folder of your project that should work

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the Built Path. The .jar is simply not good.

Comment: i don't know i have used ksoaop2 jar and it works for me. google it and download the latest one it should work

Comment: Thank you, I will try again. Thank you Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using [Ksoap2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) for this.

Regarding fixing this in particular, I did some testing with SoapUI to check the WS and do some testing with the way you write your request and in fact it gives an error. Try adding tempuri.org to envelope :

```
  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                 "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " +
         "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" "+ 
         "xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\"   >  " +
```

And write the body like so :

```
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
         <tem:Celsius>30</tem:Celsius>
      </tem:CelsiusToFahrenheit>
   </soap:Body>
```

Hope This helps, and consider using [Ksoap2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) , really

Comment: Hi SysHex. Thank you very much. I indeed firstly have used ksoap2, but the .jars that code.google.com are providing are not good. They either are good just for compilation with no definition classes, or are not good at all. I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject at com.example.soap_ksoap2_lino.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) Maybe, could you please send me a good working ksoap2-android...jar?

Comment: Hi! The one I'm using now is [ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/qrpBMNFCNG/) . Get it there.